# type name not allowed and expect )

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

Hi there I have the following code trying to get it working, I keep getting type name not allowed for speed and around .x getting expect ), basically what I want to do is read the 3 D3DXVECTOR3 value inside "speed". I have made a struct speed and passed in the members, its not working, maybe I'm interpret something wrong?

```
struct velocity
{
    float x, y, z;
};

ReadProcessMemory(pHandle,
                  reinterpret_cast<void*>(pPlayerSpeed + 0x000),
                  &speed,
                  sizeof(D3DXVECTOR3),
                  nullptr);

float speed = sqrt((speed.x * speed.x) +
                   (speed.y * speed.y) +
                   (speed.z * speed.z));
```

Comment: spped is a type defined by you. You have not declared any variable of speed type.

Comment: Just want to say I love you guys so much for all the feed back, this site is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You first define a `struct` called `speed`

```
struct speed{...};
```

then try defining a `float` also named `speed`

```
float speed = ...;
```

In C++ variable names are unique, so the code is rejected. Change either the name of the `struct` or the name of the `float`.

Answer (score 0):

In this function call

```
ReadProcessMemory(pHandle,
                  reinterpret_cast<void*>(pPlayerSpeed + 0x000),
                  &speed,
                  sizeof(D3DXVECTOR3),
                  nullptr);
```

the compiler considers name `speed` in expression `&speed` as the name of type `struct speed`. You have to specify an object (as I think of this type) as the argument instead of the type name itself.

Also it is a bad idea that you named object of type float the same name as the name of `struct speed`.

It is better to rename the object or in this declaration to use the elaborated name of the structure.

```
float speed = sqrt((( struct speed).x * (struct speed).x) +
                   ((struct speed).y * (struct speed).y) +
                   ((struct speed).z * (struct speed).z));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to know the difference between types and instances of those types.
`int`, `float`, `speed`, `D3DXVECTOR3` are types. You use a type by creating instances/variables of those types and manipulating those variables:

```
int someInt = 0;
float someFloatVariable = 0.0;
speed playerSpeed = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
D3DXVECTOR3 myVect;
```

When you **call** a function, you must give it parameters that are instances of the correct types that the function is expecting. So your call to `ReadProcessMemory` is wrong in this respect. You might try something like this:

```
speed playerSpeed;
ReadProcessMemory(pHandle,
              reinterpret_cast<void*>(pPlayerSpeed + 0x000),
              &playerSpeed,     // NOTE variable name, NOT type name
              sizeof(D3DXVECTOR3),
              nullptr);
```

But this is also most likely wrong, you probably want to read a `D3DXVECTOR3` vector, not your own defined `speed` instance, so you might want to try it like this:

```
D3DXVECTOR3 playerSpeedVect;
ReadProcessMemory(pHandle,
              reinterpret_cast<void*>(pPlayerSpeedVect + 0x000),
              &playerSpeedVect,     // NOTE variable name, NOT type name
              sizeof(D3DXVECTOR3),
              nullptr);
```

Now to your second line of code:

```
float speed = sqrt((speed.x * speed.x) +
               (speed.y * speed.y) +
               (speed.z * speed.z));
```

So... you're trying to define a variable named speed of type float, which you can't do because `speed` names a type. You also try to access the members of the `struct speed` directly on the type, without an instance. To access the members you need an instance (the instance is the *thing* that actually keeps a value in some memory location, the type only describes what an instance looks like and what it can do).
So to use your `speed` structure you might do something like this:

```
speed playerSpeed;
playerSpeed.x = 1.2;
playerSpeed.y = 2.0;
playerSpeed.z = 2.5;

float computedValue = sqrt(playerSpeed.x * playerSpeed.y + playerSpeed.z);
```

Now going back to your code, it would probably be better to completely remove your speed struct and just use `D3DXVECTOR3`. So declare a variable of type `D3DXVECTOR3`, use it in the call to `ReadProcessMemory` as above, and use it's members to compute the value you need.

Comment: hi @Ionut Thanks for the awesome reply, it really help me a lot , but I'm still kinda confused on how to use the members in D3DXVECTOR3 playerSpeedVect to calculate the value I want. If its not too much trouble can you please post an example code please?

Comment: If `D3DXVECTOR3` is the one from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205546(v=vs.85).aspx) then it looks very similar to the `struct` you were trying to define and you use it exactly the same: `sqrt(playerSpeedVect.x * playerSpeedVect.y + playerSpeedVect.z) ` where `playerSpeedVect` is a variable of type `D3DXVECTOR3`.

Comment: On a separate note, you should really take the time to learn C++ syntax and concepts before going into stuff like DirectX or `ReadProcessMemory()`.